# Look for string in arraylist element and pair it with specific image

Tags: java, image, jsp, servlets, arraylist

Im trying to do a MVC application with Model , JSP and Servlet.

From my Model I get an arrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Each element look like this example: `96125;www.qwerty.com`
Lets say I have a image named: **www.qwerty.com.png**

I want to take myArrayList pass it from my servlet to the jsp. So lets say I call for `myArrayList[0]` and the first element is `96125;www.qwerty.com` I want it to show the image **www.qwerty.com.png** in my JSP instead of the actual element.

How can I solve this?

Comment: use html img tag `www.qwerty.com.png`. `<img src="www.qwerty.com.png"/>`

Comment: I cant do it just like that. Because element[1] maybe is: `213231;www.asdfgh.com` and the next day element[1] will be element[0].

Comment: What does your JSP file look like?

Comment: Its just a plain JSP file auto generated from Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

For getting just the image name, you can use split method of String Class:

```
    myArrayList[0].split(";")[1]
```